# Hadoop table source details

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, oozie, hue

I have a hadoop table and I need to find the source type(relational/flatfile/mainframe) of the table. I have access to hue, logs of table. May I know how can I extract those details?

Comment: Is `describe formatted _your-table_` output not sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: I tried it but I am only able to get the table type whether it is internal or external. I need the source transmission type

Comment: I see. So you're talking about data lineage? Afaik, that requires additional tools like Apache Atlas, Cloudera Navigator, or the like.

Comment: I have no idea what those are

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the source of the data from a hive table. Hive/Impala tables only holds the information and metadata about the data. It doesn't holds where it came from. For e.g. if you are loading the data from a mainframe system using [Sqoop](https://sqoop.apache.org/), then you can load the data into a hadoop system in avro, parquet, compressed, delimited, etc. or into a hive table.

If you really want to understand the lineage of your data, you need to look for enterprise solutions like [Cloudera Navigator](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/datamgmt.html). The discussion of this topic is too broad for this forum.

Cloudera Navigator Lineage URL : https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cn_iu_lineage.html

Comment: May I know how do I fetch those details from cloudera Navigator?

Comment: check this link: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cn_iu_lineage.html